# Getting 0x55555555 just using numbers less then 0xFF, | and <<

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Very basic practice problem that is massively confusing me for some reason.
I have the number 0x55555555 that I want to get in C using only the bit-wise operators | and <<. You can also use any number less then 0xFF as part of shift/or. Lastly less then 6 operators have to be used, so I can't just spam shifts one at a time and then | with 5.

The issue for me is that I am struggling to figure out how to get the 5/0101 to repeat. I can of course just shift 5 over, however that just leaves 0's behind such as this (5<<4 -> 0101 0000).

```
int test () {return (5<<21);}
```

Comment: You have to shift and then combine with the `|` operator.

Comment: Can you use variables, or does this need to be just one expression?

Comment: @Barmar: you mean something like this ((((5<<4)|5)<<4)|5), but expanded? because that takes up way too many operators.

Comment: @MaxJones However it would only use 4 if you started with 0x55, and then divide and conquer.

Comment: @MaxJones Use a loop.

Comment: Ugh yeah I just need to use 0x55 and break it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
uint32_t _55 = 0x55;
uint32_t _5555 = (_55 << 8) | _55;
uint32_t _55555555 = (_5555 << 16) | _5555;
```

Comment: Very nice, only 4 operators.